# Convert array to string and back, without losing information

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell

I need to run a bash script which generates a bash array, and somehow return this array to a bash calling script. The resulting array, as returned to the calling script, must be identical to the original in every respect: no character (like space) is to be treated specially. Also, the scripts must be separate processes, as I can't afford to execute the other script in the context of the former.

This is made harder due to the inability of bash functions to accept or return arrays without hacks. Despite encoding/decoding the array, which could be complicated and slow, what is the simplest (least coding) or fastest (execution speed) way to do this?

Comment: And what is it you want to carry in your array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given an array -- associative or not:

```
$ typeset -a array
$ array=({1..10})
```

Your *serialized* array would be given by:

```
$ typeset -p array
declare -a array='([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" \
    [4]="5" [5]="6" [6]="7" [7]="8" [8]="9" [9]="10")'
```

This is about to work both while *coming* and *going*, as `typeset/declare -p name` gives you the exact construction command of a declared variable.

The result is the string with the declaration itself, from which you can have your array *evaluated back* -- tested with GNU bash, version 4.2.24:

```
$ declaration=$(typeset -p array)
$ eval ${declaration}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great, I didn't really accept that this would be built into bash.

Answer (score 1):

The other way to do this cleanly is with a NUL-delimited stream, which has the advantage that you can read it from languages and tools other than bash. To generate that stream:

```
printf '%s\0' "${your_array[@]}"
```

...and, to read it in:

```
your_array=()
while IFS='' read -r -d '' entry; do
  your_array+=( "$entry" )
done
```

This also has the advantage of not requiring that the code generating the data be trusted, as does use of `eval`.

---

For an associative or sparse array, one can emit pairs:

```
for key in "${!your_array[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\0' "$key" "${your_array[$key]}"
done
```

...and, for readback:

```
declare -A your_array # if associative
while IFS='' read -r -d '' key && IFS='' read -r -d '' value; do
  your_array["$key"]="$value"
done
```